# Mongo aggregation query: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, mongodb, recursion

Dealing with a fairly large Mongo dataset here and gathering some high-level information on it.

When I run this aggregate query on my dataset

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id: '$d',
            counts: {
               //sum of array size across a department
              '$sum': {
                  '$size': '$dataset'
              }
            }          
        }
    },
    {$sort: { total: -1 }}
])
```

I get the following response on RoboMongo

```
InternalError: too much recursion
```

Can someone with knowledge of Mongo internals and javascript explain to me what part of the query is falling over and how I can remedy this?

Thank you.

Comment: That is not a MongoDB error and certainly has nothing to do with the query you are running. It will in fact be an error coming from RoboMongo itself. I suggest you update and if the problem still persists then I suggest you are not showing us everything you are actually running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I would have done this as a comment, but I am still not allowed to comment your question.

I know this as a javascript error. Sadly literally everything like a loop can be implemented with recursion inside of mongodb.

One question: Have you mismatched the fieldname `counts` from your $group-stage with `total` in the $sort-stage?

To hunt down the error I would try out the following:

1) I'd try to separate the stages: Do you get the error with the $group-stage without the $sort-stage and vice versa.
2) I'd try a subset of 'collection': put a $match-stage or so before the $group-stage 
3) I'd Try use replace the $size operator with something simpler (at least with an operator, that is not processing arrays)
4) I'd replace the $sum-operator with some other group-accumulator-operator.

Comment: Yup, that's what happened. I mismatched total and counts. Good troubleshooting advice as well.

Comment: Thank you for being so kind and accepting the answer even if you figured it out by yourself at the same time or even some moments earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I was sorting by total, which I never define and I assume references something strange inside Mongo or RoboMongo.

When I changed it to sort by counts, it went through just fine.